# Return type for python's search and match in re module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, return-type

Documenting return types for methods and I have:

```
@classmethod
def rightFileType(cls, fileName):
    """Check if the filetype (extension) is correct for subclass.
    :type fileName: str | unicode
    :rtype: _sre.SRE_Match | None # here ?
    """
    return cls.file_extension.search(fileName)
```

It does not feel right to use a private module but the docs refer to a `re.MatchObject` class that I can't seem to locate in `re` - pycharm can't resolve that symbol. So here is re.MatchObject in python's re module - or what should I use for return type here ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you would like to return a bool type.
Then:

```
if cls.file_extesion.search(fileName):
    return True
return False
```

But, I don't know why you use regex here, you can check the filename with `endswith` method of `str`.

Comment: This is not the complete method - I do not only check the extension and I want to return the full match object - so I need an answer to the question - not being told to return a bool - if wanted a bool I could just return that no ?